# "Check for duplicates" error when I am trying to sort dataframe by datetime64

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime64

I am trying to sort a dataframe by date like this :

```
result = result.sort_values(by=result.CF_FACT_DATFACT, ascending=True)
```

**CF_FACT_DATFACT** is a datetime64.
 by executing this command I have this error :

> KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>   ----> 1 result = result.sort_values(by=result.CF_FACT_DATFACT, ascending=True)# group bills by client sort ascending by date of bill
>
> /home/houssem/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.pyc
>   in sort_values(self, by, axis, ascending, inplace, kind, na_position) 
>   4717     4718             by = by[0]
>   -> 4719             k = self._get_label_or_level_values(by, axis=axis)    4720     4721             if isinstance(ascending, (tuple, list)):
>
> /home/houssem/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.pyc
>   in _get_label_or_level_values(self, key, axis)    1704
>   values = self.axes[axis].get_level_values(key)._values    1705
>   else:
>   -> 1706             raise KeyError(key)    1707     1708         # Check for duplicates
>
> KeyError: 0         2015-08-24 1         2016-04-01 2
>   2017-04-24 3         2017-03-10 4         2017-05-12 5
>   2018-02-02 6         2018-02-03 7         2018-03-04 8
>   2018-03-05 9         2018-03-07 10        2018-02-08 11
>   2018-04-12 12        2019-04-02 13        2019-04-03 14
>   2019-02-07 15        2019-03-09 16        2007-04-06 17
>   2007-03-07 18        2007-02-11 19        2007-04-12 20
>   2009-04-08 21        2010-05-01 22        2010-02-03 23
>   2010-03-08 24        2011-03-01 25        2011-02-12 26
>   2012-04-06 27        2012-03-07 28        2012-04-12 29
>   2013-04-02
>                ...     3617565   2010-04-10 3617566   2010-04-10 3617567   2011-08-02 3617568   2011-08-02 3617569   2011-08-06 3617570
>   2011-08-06 3617571   2011-06-10 3617572   2011-06-10 3617573
>   2012-05-30 3617574   2012-05-30 3617575   2012-01-10 3617576
>   2012-01-10 3617577   2013-05-30 3617578   2013-05-30 3617579
>   2013-09-27 3617580   2013-09-27 3617581   2014-01-30 3617582
>   2014-01-30 3617583   2015-03-02 3617584   2015-03-02 3617585
>   2009-03-07 3617586   2009-03-07 3617587   2013-06-02 3617588
>   2013-06-02 3617589   2014-05-27 3617590   2014-05-27 3617591
>   2014-09-25 3617592   2014-09-25 3617593   2016-02-02 3617594
>   2016-02-02 Name: CF_FACT_DATFACT, Length: 3617595, dtype:
>   datetime64[ns]

I don't understand the problem, is the duplicated values raise errors when sorting a dataframe?

Comment: You should try this syntax: `result = result.sort_values(by='CF_FACT_DATFACT', ascending=True)`. Mine tries to sort the dataframe using the column values. Yours tries to sort the dataframe using the columns *as a pandas `Series`*. And then pandas has to pair the indexes which is not possible if there are duplicates in index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to fix this problem the by argument must take a string or a table of strings that indicate the columns on which I will apply the sort